# Loop through all td of next() table

Tags: jquery

I want to loop through each td of a table which is next of $this button clicked

```
<input type="button" class='btn'>   
<table><tr><td></td></tr>......</table>   

<input type="button" class='btn'>   
<table><tr><td></td></tr>......</table>   

<input type="button" class='btn'>   
<table><tr><td></td></tr>......</table>   

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    $()ready(function(){   
       $(".btn").click(function(){
          //loop through each td of next table??????
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/umodum/1/edit)**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){   
       $(".btn").click(function(){
          //loop through each td of next table??????
           $(this).next().find('td').each(function(){
            });
       });
 });
```

Comment: @sneha khan I have added the link of live demo and updated the answer, for dome http://jsbin.com/umodum/1/edit